# Get derivative in R

Tags: r, math, derivative

I'm trying to take the derivative of an expression:

```
x = read.csv("export.csv", header=F)$V1
f = expression(-7645/2* log(pi) - 1/2 * 
       sum(log(w+a*x[1:7644]^2)) + (x[2:7645]^2/(w + 
       a*x[1:7644]^2)),'a')
D(f, 'a')
```

`x` is simply an integer vector, `a` and `w` are the variables I'm trying to find by deriving. However, I get the error

```
"Function '`[`' is not in Table of Derivatives"
```

Since this is my first time using R I'm rather clueless what to do now. I'm assuming R has got some problem with my sum function inside of the expression?

---

After following the advice I now did the following:

```
y <- x[1:7644]
z <- x[2:7645]

f = expression(-7645/2* log(pi) - 
       1/2 * sum(log(w+a*y^2)) + (z^2/(w + a*y^2)), 'a')
```

Deriving this gives me the error "sum is not in the table of derivatives". How can I make sure the expression considers each value of `y` and `z`?

---

Another Update:

```
y <- x[1:7644]
z <- x[2:7645]

f = expression(-7645/2* log(pi) - 1/2 * log(w+a*y^2) + 
       (z^2/(w + a*y^2)))

d = D(f, 'a')

uniroot(eval(d), c(0, 1000))
```

I've eliminated the "sum" function and just entered y and z. Now, 2 questions:

a) How can I be sure that this is still the expected behavior?
b) Uniroot doesn't seem to like "w" and "a" since they're just symbolic. How would I go about fixing this issue? The error I get is "object 'w' not found"

Comment: Hi, I've gotten to here now:
`y <- x[1:7644]
z <- x[2:7645]

f = expression(-7645/2* log(pi) - 1/2 * sum(log(w+a*y^2)) + (z^2/(w + a*y^2)),'a')

D(f,'a')`

However, the derivate for every variable (x,w,a) is always zero. That doesn't seem right to me. I figured I'd get a new expression. How would I do that?

Comment: That's a good description of your try, but craft a simple example with 10 values, do the maths by yourself to get expected output, put this here with an explanation of what's you're trying to achieve and you'll probably get a good answer

Comment: I understand that I haven't defined `w` - I'm trying to find out what  `w` and `a` are going to be by deriving the expression and finding the root. How would I go about defining them?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Since you have two terms being added `f+g`, the derivative `D(f+g) = D(f) + D(g)`, so let's separate both like this:

```
g = expression((z^2/(w + a*y^2)))
f = expression(- 1/2 * log(w+a*y^2))
```

See that `sum()` was removed from expression f, because the multiplying constant was moved into the `sum()` and the `D(sum()) = sum(D())`. Also the first constant was removed because the derivative is 0.

So:

```
D(sum(-7645/2* log(pi) - 1/2 * log(w+a*y^2)) + (z^2/(w + a*y^2)) = D( constant + sum(f) + g ) = sum(D(f)) + D(g)
```

Which should give:

```
sum(-(1/2 * (y^2/(w + a * y^2)))) + -(z^2 * y^2/(w + a * y^2)^2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said this is within my first 15 minutes of using R since I can't use Matlab any longer so sorry for further stupid questions - I see this has simplified it a lot.

However, I cannot simply use df = D(g,'a') + D(f,'a') since I'm getting a "non numeric argument to binary operator"-error.

I'm starting to feel like R wasn't exactly made for Symbolic Math.

Answer (score 1):

expression takes only a single expr input, not a vector, and it is beyond  r abilities to vectorize that.
you can also do this with a for loop:

```
foo <- c("1+2","3+4","5*6","7/8") 
result <- numeric(length(foo))
foo <- parse(text=foo)
for(i in seq_along(foo))
    result[i] <- eval(foo[[i]])
```